# uWSGI 400 Bad Request

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I am trying to server a python app over uWSGI/nginx. `Ubuntu 21.10`  `uWSGI 2.0.20`

The app has a couple of endpoints :

1. a GET that is used for testing (it simply returns the string "hello")
2. a POST endpoint with a different route which accepts some json data and returns some output.

The app runs in a hosted environment.

- When I tried putting it behind nginx server, the GET end point worked properly but the POST retuned with 400
- I then tried to only run the app via flask, (no uWSGI/nginx), BOTH the endpoints worked.
- Then I shut down the flask process and run uWSGI via command line:

`uwsgi --socket 0.0.0.0:5555 --protocol=http -w runserver:app`

In this case, GET works properly,

```
[pid: 19308|app: 0|req: 5/5] 103.113.137.67 () {36 vars in 705 bytes} [Tue Nov 23 08:21:12 2021] GET / => generated 5 bytes in 0 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 2 headers in 78 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
```

but POST fails

```
[pid: 19308|app: 0|req: 2/2] 103.113.137.67 () {26 vars in 394 bytes} [Tue Nov 23 07:52:40 2021] POST /distance/term => generated 187 bytes in 1 msecs (HTTP/1.1 400) 2 headers in 89 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
```

(nginx as reverse proxy is configured to listen to the port 55555 so uWSGI on 5555 doesn't lead to port conflict)

So:

- App is not a problem. Otherwise the flask would have crashed too
- Nginx config doesn't seem to be a problem; GET endpoint works properly

How do I go about debugging this problem?

Answer (score 0):

**Repeat your error**

Since you don't post code about your POST endpoint and how do you visit your app. So I will assume your code is like following:

```py
# runserver.py
from flask import Flask
from flask import request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/post',methods=['POST'])
def post():
    data=request.form['data']
    return data

@app.route('/get',methods=['GET'])
def get():
    return "hello"
```

And you start uwsgi as you do

```bash
uwsgi --socket 0.0.0.0:5555 --protocol=http -w runserver:app
```

Suppose you are visiting your app in bash by

```bash
curl -X POST http://localhost:5555/post -d '{"data": "someData"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

Then you can see following in bash which indicates a 400 bad request error.

```bash
<!doctype html>
<html lang=en>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.</p>
```

At the same time, if you visit GET endpoint by `curl http://localhost:5555/get` you can receive "hello" correctly.

**Reason:**

If you are really doing above things, then the reason is that the **mismatch** between the data type you send and the data type web app wants to parse. `request.form` is used to read data formatted as `key1=value1&key2=value2` and above request sends data formatted as `{key:value}`

**Solutions:**

If you are really doing above things, then you have two solutions:

- First solution: Change the data type of what you send. In above case, you can visit your app like

`curl -X POST http://localhost:5555/post -d "data=someData"  -H 'Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`

, which sends data formatted as `key=value` and `request.form` can parse it correctly. You can see the result `someData` in bash.

- Second solution: Change how web app parses the data. If you send data formatted as json, then you can replace `request.form` with `request.json` in your `runserver.py` like

```py
@app.route('/post',methods=['POST'])
def post():
    data=request.json['data']
    return data
```

Then visit your app like

`curl -X POST http://localhost:5555/post -d '{"data": "someData"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'`

, and you will see the result `someData` in bash.